# How to get view parents name

Tags: java, android

I know I can get views name in android. But how I do to compare the name? Please tell me

Thats my logcat output:

```
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout{e888acb V.E...... ........ 0,939-1080,1458 #7f0d00bd app:id/menuCust}
```

This is what Ive tried:

```
if(view.getParent.toString().equals("myConstraintLayoutName")){

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to compare views by name?

Comment: Im using drag and drop. I need to know what is the view that child is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views don't really have names.  They have ids, which don't use a string representation (they use integers for speed).  So you'd do something like view.getParent().getId() == R.id.myConstraintLayoutName